# Почему PhpStorm не подключается по ftp?

Tags: phpstorm, ftp

Почему PhpStorm не подключается по ftp?

Необходимо подключиться по ftp.

Браузеры, Firezilla, Putty и обычный Windows Explorer в Windows 10 нормально подключаются.

Passive mode отключал и включал, не работает.

`Could not connect to FTP server on "x.x.x.x".`

Comment: Наверное, какую-то ошибку выдает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да, дополнил.

Comment: Сервер живой, стоит на 21 порту. Брендмауер у вас не блокирует приложение PHPStorm?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, нет

Comment: Putty и IE работают на этой же машине?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, не ie, а explorer. но да, моя ошибка. он называется windows explorer. проводник, короче. но да, Ie на этой же машине, как и патти, и в ие, проводнике и патти все норм коннектится, а в пхпсторме - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

странная штука:

делаю копипаст пароля в пхпсторм - не работает.

в остальные работает.

набираю руками в пхпсторм - работает. мда.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию ошибки "не может подключиться к серверу" я бы посоветовал, проверить:
**тип соединения** - быть может у вас выбран `sftp/ftps/ssh`;
**FTP host** - может ошиблись у `ip` в цифре или в доменном имени;
**Port** - быть может у сервака не стандартный `21`, а другой;

Так же возможно в дополнительном окне настроек "**advanced options"**
стоит поставить галочку "***Compatibility mode***" *(у меня бывало требовало)*

либо просто сам сервер не доступен.

Comment: тип соединения - ftp, хост верный (копипастил), порт правильный. тем более что в пати все то же самое